# The preposition "down" in this context?

Tags: meaning, grammar

I already know what "glare at" means (look angrily at someone) but I don't understand the use of "down" in this context:

"I peeked up at him one more time, and regretted it. He was glaring down at me again, his black eyes full of revulsion."

Thanks

Comment: *Down* and *up* indicate the relative positions of the two characters: the narrator's eye level is below that of that of 'he'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [StoneyB](https://www.ell.stackexchange.com/users/32/stoneyb) said, the preposition “down” means that “he” was glaring downwards at the narrator, who must be at a lower level than “he”.